# Compute hyperbolic length of the arc of the circle

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Compute the hyperbolic length of the arc of the circle $ x^2 + y^2 = 25$ that lies between (3, 4)  and  (4, 3).

From my notes I know the formula is $$ \ln \frac{{\csc \beta  - \cot \beta }}{{\csc \alpha  - \cot \alpha }} $$

however I don't know how to find $\beta$ and $\alpha$

Comment: can you give more information? (which book are you using, which model  and so on

Comment: I assume that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the two sharp angles of the $(3,4;5)$ straight-edged triangle.